# How to login using the test_client and use app_context of that login to issue a PUT request?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest, flask-restful

I am writing pytests for testing the API calls. First, I use the POST api to log the user in. Then I need to test a PUT api that allows the logged in user to edit profile info. The PUT api first checks whether g.current_user.id = id of the profile to be edited. But while in pytest, the put request raises the following error: 
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'current_user'

I have been trying to use the same app_context in both, the POST and the PUT api. I was trying to use current_app, but same error is encountered.

These are the test assertions. The first one passes, second one fails:

```
with test_client as client:
        login = {'username':'washington', 'password':'FlaskIsAwesome'}
        l = client.post('/auth/login', data=login, follow_redirects=True)
        assert l.status_code == 200

        u = json.loads(client.put('api/users/1', data=updateuser, headers=headers).data)
        assert u == json.loads(client.get('api/users/1').data)
```

This is test_client in the conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def test_client():
    flask_app = create_app('test')

    flask_app.config['TESTING'] = True

    # Flask provides a way to test your application by exposing
    # the Werkzeug test Client and handling the context locals
    # for you.
    testing_client = flask_app.test_client()

    # Establish an application context before running the tests.
    ctx = flask_app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    yield testing_client  # this is where the testing happens!

    ctx.pop()
```

This is how the PUT api is defined:

```py
    def put(self, id):
        """
        Updates the profile information of a user
        """
        if g.current_user.id != id:
            abort(403)
        user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
        data = request.get_json() or {}
        if 'username' in data and data['username'] != user.username and \
                User.query.filter_by(username=data['username']).first():
            return bad_request('please use a different username')
        if 'email' in data and data['email'] != user.email and \
                User.query.filter_by(email=data['email']).first():
            return bad_request('please use a different email address')
        user.from_dict(data, new_user=False)
        db.session.commit()
        return user.to_dict()
```

I expect that the PUT request successfully updates the profile information of the user, who is logged in through the POST request earlier. It returns the updated details of user in the form of a python dictionary.

But I have been facing this single error:
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'current_user'

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138025/attributeerror-appctxglobals-object-has-no-attribute-user-in-flask)

Comment: Yes I referred it, but didn't help. I think its the pytest thats causing this error...